# Jsoup interesting parse, nothing printed

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm parsing  articles of news.
I did successfuly parse two articles of news.
But in third I have interesting problem.
here is code.

```
case 2://Radikal
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(gazete.getAdress()).get();
                    mainElement = doc.select("div.author");

                    System.out.println(mainElement);
                    for (Element element : mainElement) {

                        String yazar = element.select("span.name").text();
                        yazar +=" " +element.select("span.surname").text();
                        String baslik = element.select("a h4").text();
                        String yaziAdress = element.select("div.article a").attr("abs:href");
                        KoseYazarlariClass ky = new KoseYazarlariClass();
                        ky.setYazarName(yazar);
                        ky.setBaslik(baslik);
                        ky.setYaziAdress(yaziAdress);
                        koseYazarlariList.add(ky);
                        System.out.println(yazar);
                        System.out.println(baslik);
                        System.out.println(yaziAdress);
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

[here is I'm trying  to parse](http://www.radikal.com.tr/yazarlar/tum_yazarlar/#kategori)

[here is image of parse html tag](http://i.hizliresim.com/zAB0gj.jpg)

Moreover,android debug on breakpoint does not work,so I cant see mainElement what it have. I print something before for element and I did see that on logcat. I did print something on for element I couldnt see that.This mean program dont enter the for element. Also,I did try to print main element before for element,I could not see that on logcat.Also I changed select element to getElementByClass method and does not work. Something wrong with this code

```
 mainElement = doc.select("div.author");
```

mainElement is not null since I did print it and no error.If we look adress of trying to parse html link there is div with class author.

What is wrong? Nothing printed with yazar,baslik,and yaziAdress never entered to for loop

***Update Edit:***

Instead of `System.out.println` I used `Log.d("burda",mainElement.text());`

got messeage like this:

```
05-21 07:38:37.428    4792-4937/yazlm.beyaz.keyazarlar D/burda﹕ [ 05-21 07:38:37.648  4792: 4792 I/Choreographer ]
```

also did get have a lot of messeage

```
05-21 07:38:34.088    4792-4792/yazlm.beyaz.keyazarlar I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

***Update 2***

I think I found the problem.When jsoup trying to connect to url adress It's redirected to m."url adress". I'm thinking that because I printed the redirected adress with this code

```
 Connection t = Jsoup.connect(gazete.getAdress()).followRedirects(false);
                            doc=t.get();
                            Connection.Response response = t.execute();
                            System.out.println(response.url());
```

Using this code It print m adress.But when I try this code

```
  Connection t = Jsoup.connect(gazete.getAdress()).followRedirects(false);
```

It is not give redirected adress but I thnik It's redirected because still no work. Any help appreciated that

Comment: did u tried this.doc.select("div.authors-area");It seems that div.author needs a parent.

Comment: I used ever parent nothing work

Answer (score 0):

this codes (nearly same as yours) works for me

```
public class Gazete {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.radikal.com.tr/yazarlar/tum_yazarlar/").get();

        Elements mainElement = doc.select("div.author");

        System.out.println(mainElement);
        for (Element element : mainElement) {

            String yazar = element.select("span.name").text();
            yazar +=" " +element.select("span.surname").text();
            String baslik = element.select("a h4").text();
            String yaziAdress = element.select("div.article a").attr("abs:href");


            System.out.println(yazar);
            System.out.println(baslik);
            System.out.println(yaziAdress);
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
    }

}
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I used Log.d("burda",mainElement.text()); and got messega like this 05-21 07:30:35.520    1231-1368/yazlm.beyaz.keyazarlar D/burda﹕ [ 05-21 07:30:35.700  1231: 1231 I/Choreographer ]

Comment: I think my Android Studio bugged